# SVG tags in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, svg-icon

Is there a way to use SVG tags in lightning components? I would like to build and display about 6 SVG icons, but unable to use `<svg>` tag in the component. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I would imagine it's possible; the slds icons are svg's [link](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/)

Comment: But I'd like to use my own icons, something I built on my own. Could use it as a static resource, but I would set the icon color based on certain conditions. For this, I need the `<svg>` tags on the component.

Answer (score 1):

One option here is to use a visualforce page to generate the svg, and use a query string parameter to set the color. Then you can include an `img` tag in your lightning component that references the visualforce page, and have the color set by a component attribute.

Circle.page

```
<apex:page 
 contentType="image/svg+xml"
 controller="Circle"
>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="200" 
     height="200">

        <circle 
         cx="100" 
         cy="100" 
         r="50" 
         stroke="black"
         stroke-width="1" 
         fill="{! Color }" 
        />

    </svg>

</apex:page>
```

Circle.cls

```
public class Circle {

    private String Color ;

    public  String getColor(){
        return this.Color ;
    }

    public Circle(){
        Color = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('color');
    }

}
```

circle.cmp

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute 
     name="color" 
     type="string"
     default="rgb(53,64,200)"
    />

    <img 
     src="{! 'https://analysis-dev-ed--analysis.ap7.visual.force.com/apex/Circle?color=' + v.color }" 
    />

</aura:component>
```

myApp.app

```
<aura:application >

    <c:Circle 
     color="blue" 
    />

    <c:Circle 
     color="red" 
    />

    <c:Circle 
     color="yellow" 
    />

    <c:Circle 
     color="green" 
    />

</aura:application>
```

---

And there you have a lightning component with an svg image where you can change the color based on component attribute values:

[image]